# Script to Run Saved Search and Render in PDF Template

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a use case where we need to create a saved search and an advanced PDF template to go with it. I need a script to run the search and render the custom PDF template I made. It seems like this is all possible. I have it so the saved search loads fine. I can’t get the search to fill in the template though. Error says: “Missing parameters required to generate PDF”.  Can someone help me get this going in the right direction?

The script:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
require(['N/search', 'N/render', 'N/email', 'N/file'], function(search, render, email, file) {
    function runSearchAndFetchResult() {
        try {

            var mySearch = search.load({
                id: 2825
            });
 
            var searchResult = mySearch.run().getRange({
                start: 0,
                end: 10
            });
            log.debug('searchResult', searchResult);
            var renderer = render.create();
            renderer.templateContent = renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("custtmpl_nscs_bin_label");

            renderer.templateContent = renderer.renderAsString();;

            renderer.addSearchResults({
                templateName: 'results',
                searchResult: searchResult
            });
            
            var newfile = renderer.renderAsPdf();
            
            newfile.name = 'Testpdf2.pdf';
            newfile.folder = 2754;
            
            // Save the file
            newfile.save();

        } catch (e) {
            log.error({
                title: 'Error',
                details: 'An error occurred: ' + e.message
            });
        }
    }

    runSearchAndFetchResult();
});
```

The Advance PDF template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH">
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <style type="text/css">table { font-size: 9pt; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
th { font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px 6px 3px; background-color: #e3e3e3; color: #333333; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; }
td { padding: 4px 6px; }
b { font-weight: bold; color: #333335; }
</style>
</head>
<body margin-left="-35" margin-top="-35" size="2.5in x 1in">
  <#list results as result>
       <table float="left">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style='font-weight:bold; font-size: 14pt;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${result.binnumber}</td>
</tr>
        
         
    <#if result?has_next>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="false" value="${result.binnumber}"></barcode></td>
    </tr></table>
        <pbr />
    <#else>
         <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><barcode codetype="code128" showtext="false" value="${result.binnumber}"></barcode></td>
    </tr></table>
    </#if>

    </#list>
</body>
</pdf>
```

[The Advance PDF Template setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8flVN.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `renderer.setTemplateByScriptId()`, that function updates the value of `renderer.templateContent` - you don't need to assign it.

Then you call `renderer.renderAsString()` and assign that to `renderer.templateContent` also.  The `renderer.renderAsString()` method returns an xml string which can be used later with a call to `render.xmlToPdf()` and would not be needed in your example (note that `xmlToPdf()` is a method of the `render` module, whereas the others shown are methods of the `TemplateRenderer` object.)

To put these comments into practice, replace the following lines:

```
renderer.templateContent = renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("custtmpl_nscs_bin_label");

renderer.templateContent = renderer.renderAsString();;
```

with:

```
renderer.setTemplateByScriptId({
    scriptId: "custtmpl_nscs_bin_label"
});
```

I haven't had time to set up a test of this example so there could be other errors I'm overlooking, but hope that helps get you on the right path.